# Setting page margins for SVG map export in QGIS Print Composer

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, mapping, svg

Is there a way to setup the print composer so that when you export your map to SVG it cuts everything that's out of the page margins?

Everytime I export my map to SVG (my page is 240x180mm), when i open it with Inkscape, there are polygons and lines that are drawn out of the page limits.